# Change CSS styles based on width of page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up an A/B test on the header of our website. The way our software works, I cannot set CSS styles unless:

1. The class/ID is unique to one variation.
2. you want the css to be applied to all variations.

So what I am trying to do is recreate media queries using jQuery, so that I can restyle the header make sure that it looks correctly at all sizes. This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 1380) {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","0");
     } elseif ((width <= 1380) && (width > 1020))  {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","100px");
     } elseif ((width <= 1020) && (width > 750))  {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","40px");
     } elseif (width <= 750)  {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","150px");
     }

});
```

When I insert this into the program, it gives me back errors stating that there should be semi-colons after the else if statements, for example:

```
elseif ((width <= 1380) && (width > 1020))
```

should be

```
elseif ((width <= 1380) && (width > 1020));
```

So I fix this on each elseif, and after that is done I get an error saying that $(window).width(); is not a function. Does anyone have any input on this? I am completely lost as to what is going wrong here. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You should be doing this with the @media css element.

Comment: That is how it would be done when the change is implemented in the code of our live site. But for now, it is inside of optimizely. I cannot set a media query in this case because it would be applied to both the original and the new variation. I am trying to rearrange the header of the site.

Comment: I dont really understand the downvotes, I was very clear that I know I should use media queries but cannot in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`else if` has a space

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 1380) {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","0");
     } else if ((width <= 1380) && (width > 1020))  {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","100px");
     } else if ((width <= 1020) && (width > 750))  {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","40px");
     } else if (width <= 750)  {
        $("logo").css("margin-top","150px");
     }

});
```

when the interpreter sees `elseif(...)` it looks like a function call which is why it's telling you to add  a `;`

Comment: i changed this and it is now saying that var width = $(window).width(); is not a function

Comment: Also, you could simplify your conditionals by dropping all of the `width <=` bits since it's necessarily `<=` at that point (if it weren't it wouldn't've passed a previous condition)

Comment: Used in the console of our site, your code does not bring up any errors but it does not set the css rules at all.

Comment: @Puzzle84: if jQuery is loaded, that would give you the function pointer itself, not the width.  You may be suggesting `$(window)[0].width` which is probably undefined since `width` isn't normally defined on the `window` object (although, it could be defined as a global variable)

Comment: @idontwantnoscrubs: used in the console, you'd want to use only the body of the callback function. `document.ready` has already occurred so it won't trigger your script.

Comment: this is working on load, is there a way that it can also changed based on resizing the window?

Comment: $(window).resize(function () { <your logic here> });

Comment: i'm sorry this is taking so many comments, but now the code works only when you resize the browser. When the page loads it still shows the original position, but when i make the window wider or smaller then the code works.

Comment: `resize` only triggers the handler on resizing events (when you change the window size).  You should also trigger it on load.  So combine both solutions and you should be good! (Tip: save the function to a variable (`var handler = function() { ... };`) and pass that as the handler to both the `onload` and `onresize` events and you'll only have to write it once!)

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this with the @media css element:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1380px) {
    .logo {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1020px) and (max-width: 1379px) {
    .logo {
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
}
```

Etcetera

Comment: You can delete (button at bottom of your answer) if you think it's no longer relevant.

Comment: Answer is still relevant, just not to this particular question. but i'd hate to see people use javascript to solve this problem in general.

Comment: True, it's a good general reference (and not incorrect, so no downvote :) ).  I guess, in a way, my comment now falls into that same territory of "not relevant to intended audience but could be useful general knowledge"

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you don't do elseif this way.

You gotta use `else if`.
check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

But, after all, you should do this using @media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1380px) { 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider Switch Case opposed to multiple else ifs:

```
switch(true){
      case(width > 1380):
          //Do stuff
      break;
      case((width <= 1380) && (width > 1020)):
          //Do stuff
      break;
      case((width <= 1020) && (width > 750)):
          //Do stuff
      break;
      default:
          // Do stuff if nothing above works

}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Also, proper santax on Else if
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: In short, yes. for this case.

The function inside of jQuery(document).ready(); fires when jQuery determines the document has fully loaded. It also encapsulates the code within the function so that any vars assigned do not affect any global variables.

Because your code is going to modify CSS rules of DOM elements, you need to run only after the DOM is fully loaded, so document ready is a good place to put the code in this case, yes.